# $remote_addr causes index.php to not rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm hosting a Wordpress blog using PHP-FPM and Nginx. A month ago, I modified the Nginx config file for the webpage to return code 503 if a file called maintenance.html exists in $document_root (and display it).

Below is the relevant section as I have it currently written:

```
location / {
# if you're just using wordpress and don't want extra rewrites
# then replace the word @rewrites with /index.php
#   try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    index index.php;

    # site goes down for maintenance if maintenance.html exists in document_root
    if (-f $document_root/maintenance.html) {
        set $maint on;
    }

     # skip specific IP's (this is causing index.php to not rewrite for these IPs)
    if ($remote_addr ~ (1.2.3.4|ano.ther.ip.address)) {
        set $maint off;
    }

    if ($maint = on) {
        return 503;
    }

    location /maintenance {
    }
}
```

Yesterday, it was brought to my attention that the blog was having issues. After some investigating, I discovered that index.php wasn't being rewritten. At the time, I had the above section written a little differently. Specifically, if $document_root/maintenance.html existed and $remote_addr =! 1.2.3.4 (where 1.2.3.4 is my home IP), the site was effectively in maintenance mode. However, it turned out that index.php wasn't being rewritten for any request coming from an IP that isn't 1.2.3.4. By modifying the if statement to how it is written above, index.php is properly rewritten for any request coming from any IP that *isn't* 1.2.3.4.

Since none of this has anything to do with PHP rewriting, I have no idea why this is happening and I'm hoping someone else might know why.

Comment: try different patterns `if ($remote_addr ~ '^1\.2\.3\.4$|^5\.6\.7\.8$')`

Comment: show full server block